# How can I rank my games by number of achievements remaining?

Tags: steam, achievements

I would like to try and get some "perfect" games on Steam - games for which I have collected all the achievements.

Obviously, some games have much bigger lists of achievements than others and some achievements are much harder than others. Can't do much about finding out the latter without playing, but I thought it would be useful/interesting if I could sort and rank my game collection by the total number of achievements or, better yet, total achievements remaining.

I can't see any way to do this in the Steam UI. Is there one, or are there any third party tools that can do this?

Comment: The answers there might answer this question, but it's not a duplicate *question*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try using [AStats](http://astats.astats.nl/astats/), it generates a list of games with achievements for your Steam account that you can sort by multiple criteria such as "number of achievements remaining" as you mention, and also by "hours to 100%" (based on how long it took other members to complete the game), and others.

It's a pretty handy website for Steam game completionists.

Answer (score 6):

I [made a thing that does this](http://seiyria.com/steam-avg-pct/). Enter your vanity URL and sort by percent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party sites such as [MetaGamerScore.com](http://metagamerscore.com/).  These type of sites periodically scan your achievements, giving you a good overview of what achievements you have unlocked (or yet to unlock).

There is also a site named TrueSteamAchievements that offers achievement tracking ([truesteamachievements.com](https://truesteamachievements.com/)).

I'm not sure about MetaGamerScore, but with TrueSteamAchievements the site shows you the percentage of registered users that have completed the achievement.  This will give you a guide to how rare an achievement actually is.  Although not always true due to other factors, it allows you to figure out the "harder" achievements to unlock.  There are also tools for filtering down achievements to, say, achievements that are acquired in single player, online etc.

When registered to TrueSteamAchievements, you can add achievements to your todo list, and view solutions to each achievement (good to check criteria, but also to see if someone has found a glitch or shortcut to cut down the hours you spend on one achievement).  There are a whole bunch of other functionality in the site too (and you can link it to your Xbox and PlayStation, if you own such a console).

Comment: _... glitch or shortcut to cut down the hours you spend on one achievement..._

If you're into that sort of thing.